# Parsing a C++ string in C++

Tags: c++

I have a requirement like this: I have a string like "-myArg:ArgVal".

```
std::string strArg = "-myArg:ArgVal";
```

Now, I have to check in above string first character is always '-' and if first character is '-' i should remove it and i should store "myArg" and "ArgVal" in two different string objects.

How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: Why are you worried about "efficiency" for something like this? How often do you need to do this? It looks like a command-line argument, which tends to imply that the parsing happens very rarely.

Comment: @unwind: Efficiency can be measured in number of lines of code, or number of programmer minutes, as well as CPU time.

Comment: Better to go for clarity in this case.  Initialization code can be pretty inefficient since it only runs once. Only optimize the stuff that takes the most runtime, and don't even worry about that until you get to the point where your program runs correctly and passes all tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
if (strArg[0] == '-') {
    strVar1 = strArg.substr(1, strArg.find(':') - 1);
    strVar2 = strArg.substr(strArg.find(':') + 1);
}
```

Of course I'm assuming that if the string starts with `'-'` then there will be a `':'` in it with chars before and after. You should probably check this because if there isn't it can cause an error

Comment: add a check for empty string, strArg[0] is not guaranteed to work

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `std::string::substr()` and `std::string::find()`.

Answer (score 1):

The most scalable and solid way is via [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). Recommended library is Boost.Regex

Comment: or in C++0x, `std::tr1::regex` or `std::regex`

Comment: I love regular expressions, but this is overkill for what the OP needs in this case.  You're putting a picture frame on the wall with a jackhammer.

Comment: @John You can say that and you'll be right. I would go for regex because the moment you need to modify this parser, or make it more complex you'll have all you need right under your nose.

Answer (score 0):

std::string has the functions you need. You can check the first char by using `string::at` and create substrings with `string::substr`. Erasing single chars works the same comfortable way.

See a [c++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) for more information.